# konva js trying to pass circle attribute variables into a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, konvajs

Here is the following function, I would like to pass the id and name values to the function, and have them used when creating the circle.
I try creating a variable with the function, but I was unable to figure out the format to use when place the vaiable after the colon.

```
function addCircle(){
        var circle = new Konva.Circle({
          x: stage.width() / 2,
          y: stage.height() / 2,
          radius: 70,
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true,
          id: 1,
          name: 'test',
        });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(circle);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    };
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla JS, ([ES2015 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)):

```
function addCircle(id, name){
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
      x: stage.width() / 2,
      y: stage.height() / 2,
      radius: 70,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true,
      id,
      name
    });
  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(circle);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
};
```

Usage:

```
addCircle(1, 'test')
```

Where

```
{
  // ...
  id,
  name
}
```

Is short-hand syntax for

```
{
  // ...
  id: id,
  name: name
}
```